# Read-only variables VS read only properties

Tags: c#, oop

```
public static string BoldStartTag { get { return "<B>"; } }
```

VS

```
   public static readonly string BoldStartTag  = "<B>";
```

or

```
public const string BoldStartTag  = "<B>";
```

which one is preferred? I would think the readonly/constant variable as I am not doing any computation in the property (just return). Also, the C# compiler will eject a method for the readonly property whereas the readonly variable will just be a variable in the IL.

Your thoughts?

Comment: Minor correction - the `const` shouldn't have `static` in front of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jeff Atwood wrote an article on [Properties vs Public Variables](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/properties-vs-public-variables.html) a while back.

I think some of the most interesting points to consider here are the ones he mentions in his update:

> - Reflection works differently on variables vs. properties, so if you rely on reflection, it's easier to use all properties.
> - You can't databind against a variable.
> - Changing a variable to a property is a breaking change.

Comment: +1 for the great link. For this specific scenario, I dont intend to do any databinding. So a constant would be good enough?

Answer (score 4):

The preferred method for public values is always a property, for encapsulation reasons.

For your specific example, though, I'd use a `const` -- it's not like `BoldStartTag` will be changing any time soon.

Comment: yeah..sure..See my edit..Just wanted to have an opinion about using the read-only property in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use const? I would have thought that having `<B>` as the bold start tag would be fairly set in stone.

Comment: yeah..sure..Just wanted to have an opinion about using the read-only property in this case.

Comment: And here I was thinking that `<b>` was the bold start tag ;-).